# How to translate componentDidMound and componentWillUnmount to UseEffect (React Hooks) with Firebase/Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How would one go about using the useEffect hook to replace both componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount while working with Firebase? I can't find a solution to this 'unsubscribe' function.

```
unsubscribe = null;

componentDidMount = async () => {
  this.unsubscribe = firestore.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    const posts = snapshot.docs.map(...)
    this.setState({ posts })
  })
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  this.unsubscribe()
}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function getSnapshot() {
  const unsubscribe = firestore.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const posts = snapshot.docs.map(...)
        setPosts(posts)
  }
  getSnapshot()
  //return something to clear it? I don't have access to 'unsubscribe'
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually pretty close with your answer. You weren't using await in your function, so there was no point in using it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = firestore.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    const posts = snapshot.docs.map(...)
    setPosts(posts);
  });
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

If you did need to use async, you can just utilize the closure to get unsubscribe out of the async function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribe;
  async function getSnapshot() {
    unsubscribe = firestore.collection('posts').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const posts = snapshot.docs.map(...)
      setPosts(posts);
    });
  }
  getSnapshot();
  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

you're probably going to run into trouble using async inside useEffect, check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-async-effect

```
useAsyncEffect( async() => {
   const unsubscribe = await firestore.collection('posts').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
       const posts = snapshot.docs.map(...)
       setPosts(posts)
    }
    return () => {
      console.log("unmount")
      unsubscribe()
    };
}, [])
```

EDIT: actually it seems from the docs that you don't need async at all there: 
have you tried this format?

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      const unsubscribe = firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('recipes')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('ingredients')
        .onSnapshot( snapshot => { const ingredients = [] snapshot.forEach(doc => { ingredients.push(doc) }) setLoading(false) setIngredients(ingredients) }, err => { setError(err) } )

      return () => unsubscribe()
    },
    [id]
  )
```